# Setting for selected text

Tags: css, focus

I am trying to override the default setting for selection. I did

```
::selection{
  background: grey;
}
```

<strike>and it looks like that takes effect when the window is not focused, but when it is focused, it does not have effect and the default color appears.</strike> It is not working. What is the correct way to do this so that is has effect irrespective of the focus?

**Edit** I think I was wrong. I want to change the color of the selected text in `<input>` tag. How can I do that?

Comment: Stick `input` before `::selection`

Answer (score 1):

It is the default browser behavior which you cannot change, when window is not focused, the selected color changes to grey, may be it denotes that the *text cannot be copied* (kinda disabled selection), so we cannot control that color

[image]

---

Example 2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using Firefox, which needs the `-moz` prefix:

```
::selection {
    color: fireBrick;
}

::-moz-selection {
    color: fireBrick;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N4AUY/**

Note that you cannot group these together. One of these won't work, so the whole rule block breaks.

Comment: No you didn't got his question, he wants the selected color to be same when window is out of focus 
:)

Comment: @Mr.Alien: You sure? *"but when it is focused, it does not have effect and the default color appears"*. It looks like it doesn't work at all and OP is mistaking the default behavior for working code.

Comment: I want to override the default whether or not focused. It partly works (when not focused, which also means that I don't need the prefix, and in fact, I am using Chrome).

Comment: @sawa: Change `grey` to `red` and see what happens.

Comment: @sawa It's a default browser effect which cannot be changed, am not sure whether jQuery or JS will do it

Comment: @Blender, Mr.Alien I think you are right. I tried with red, and it is still gray when not focused. So it looks like it is not working at all.

Comment: @sawa As I told you, it's browser default, may be because it shows the window is not focused and you **CANNOT COPY THE TEXT** of that window, kinda disabled effect, so that color cannot be changed

Answer (score 1):

Should Work fine, [See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j23J8/). the problem seems to be due to something else

```
::selection
{
background: grey;
}
::-moz-selection
{
background: grey;
}
```